Bluetooth HID device in kotlin
I am facing an issue with my app. When my app is connected to a device running Android version 12, all the functions, such as HID keyboard and mouse, work fine. However, when I connect to a device running Android version 11, only the HID keyboard function works. Moreover, if connected to a device running Android version 14, none of the functions work.
i used  BluetoothHidDevice.Callback() function and BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener ,
for registering i used  val result = bluetoothHidDevice?.registerApp(sdpSettings, null, null , executor, hidCallback) , and for sending data i used     private fun sendMouseMovement(dx: Int, dy: Int) {
connectedDevice?.let { device ->
val movementData = byteArrayOf(0x00, dx.toByte(), dy.toByte())  // No buttons, X and Y movement
        println("Attempting to send mouse movement: dx=$dx, dy=$dy")
        val success = bluetoothHidDevice?.sendReport(device, 0, movementData) ?: false
        if (success) {
            println("Mouse movement report sent successfully: dx=$dx, dy=$dy")
        } else {
            println("Failed to send mouse movement report")
        }
    }
}

